# Import .lyr files into Cesium?

Tags: shapefile, javascript, cesium, layer-file, ol-cesium

I have an application that is able to import .lyr files into a Cesium map if they are bundled with all the required associated files in a zip file.  The application treats the bundled files in the .zip file as a .shp file with its associated files.  I want the application to import the .lyr file without having to bundle the .lyr file and other required files in a zip file.  Simply the user selects the .lyr file and the application will retrieve the associated files and plot items on the map.

Is there an easy solution to uploading .lyr files this way into Cesium?

Answer (score 1):

.lyr or shapefile are not directly supported yet in cesium.

https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/cesium-ion-community/issues/7

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cesium-dev/XXK-Ap4qRg4

but you always export it to kml or geojson and upload to cesium.

Answer (score 1):

Lyr is not data, only reference to data with symbology labeling and scale dependency. Cesium supports GeoJSON, KML/KMZ, Czml